# Dumps and loads in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
  from django.utils.simplejson import dumps, loads
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


 def index(request):
   return render_to_response('test2/index.html')

 def add_lang(request):
   logging.debug("Got request")
   a = request.POST
    logging.debug(a["lang"])
   lang=dumps(a["lang"])
   l = Language(code=lang)
   l.save()
lang=loads(lang)

logging.debug(loads(l.code))
return render_to_response('test2/test21.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'test2': l.code}))
```

My question is there any way to load the variable back to its original format in the template file.i.e, i want a function similar to loads in template.I do not want to do it in views since there will be a lot of code changes

test21.html

```
    {{ test2 }}  
     //The above prints"\u0905\u0902\u0917\u094d\u0930\u0947\u091c\u093c\u0940, \u0939\u093f\u0902\u0926"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without writing a [custom filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).